# Select Option Dropdown not visible fully

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have created a dropdown using select tag but the height of that dropdown is too small, and if I try to increase the height by using **height:100px;** or **max-height: 100px;** the button below that slips down, how do I increase the height by not moving the below button down by 100px and display dropdown over it.

The code for the dropdown is:

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Select Location:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-8" style="overflow:auto;">
            <select class="form-control multiselect" multiple="multiple" role="multiselect">
                 <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                 ...
            </select>
         </div>
</div>
```

[image: Picture displaying the dropdown]

Comment: can you add running sample snippet with bootstrap reference

Comment: giving the select `position: absolute` with a height will do the job

Comment: `position:absolute` and height work fine but the same problem arises when I add `overflow:auto` to the div element for scroll.